# Terminal command "convert" not found in C program

Tags: c, terminal, command, system

i'm trying to use the convert terminal command in a C program using system function, this is the code piece

```
\#include <stdlib.h>
...
system("cd /Users/myUser/Desktop/photos/pgm;for i in *.jpg; do convert $i 
-compress none  -scale     32x24! $i.pgm; done;")
```

But I cant run the convert command, this is the program output:

```
sh: convert: command not found
```

I can run the same command in Terminal without problems

Comment: What is a "*terminal command*"?

Comment: Did you try : `*.jpg; do /full/path/to/convert $i ` ?

Comment: @alk That's the alternative name for the "last command". You're not allowed to type any other commands after it has been run.

Comment: @TurtleLoop: Are you allowed to create a shell script instead of a full command-line? Ultimately, it would prove to be a more flexible solution. To answer your question, you might have to install ImageMagick.

Comment: @alk "Terminal" is the name of the command prompt in Mac OS X

Comment: I presume the backslash on the first line isn't really there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the full path to `convert` using `which convert`.
Then exchange the full path in your C program.

Comment: perfect :) I changed it to system("cd /Users/myUser/Desktop/photos/pgm;for i in *.jpg; do /usr/local/bin/convert $i 
-compress none  -scale     32x24! $i.pgm; done;"); and it works, thanks!

Comment: Then you must not be executing your C program by invoking it from your shell. If you were, it would inherit your shell's `$PATH`. If your C program's `$PATH` included `/usr/local/bin`, you wouldn't need to specify the full path.